# Don't make push notif drop down

Tags: android, android-notifications

While during a call, I want to display a persistent push notification so that in case the user exits the app he clicks on the notification and brings him back to the screen. A problem I'm facing on Oreo (that's the only place I've noticed this) is that unlike on a 7.0, it will not just display the icon at the top, it'll dropdown the notification over the entire screen and hide it after a while. 
Is there a way to disable this functionality?
i.e: i don't want it to show like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think below method may help you. Found this in notification managerclass.

```
/**
 * Sets the current notification interruption filter.
 * <p>
 * The interruption filter defines which notifications are allowed to
 * interrupt the user (e.g. via sound &amp; vibration) and is applied
 * globally.
 * <p>
 * Only available if policy access is granted to this package. See
 * {@link #isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted}.
 */
public final void setInterruptionFilter(@InterruptionFilter int interruptionFilter) {
    final INotificationManager service = getService();
    try {
        service.setInterruptionFilter(mContext.getOpPackageName(), interruptionFilter);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        throw e.rethrowFromSystemServer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set Notification priority to `PRIORITY_DEFAULT` in android 7 and below .in android 8 and above set Importance to `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT`